# 35km difference between Google Earth and Map coordinates when manual input

Tags: google-earth, google-maps-engine

I have GPS coordinates. If i enter them manually in the Google Maps Engine, there is a 35 km distance between the points and the same coordinate in Google Earth.

However, if i import the Earth's KMZ into MAPS, they are located correctly but cannot see the coordinate.

Is there some behind the scenes conversion made by Maps?

Comment: Can you give us some coordinate examples?

Comment: Hi Mapperz. Any coordinate. Ie:  38°27'2.01"S  68°42'0.76"W